# Do not call getDocContent() method in GSA Adaptor Framework 4.1

Tags: google-search-appliance

I use the GSA Adaptor Framework 4.1 that the feed in to the GSA.
So, I have tested with a file(AdaptorTemplate.java) provided by Google.

getDocIds() method is called.(Confirm available In the Gsa Admin Console menu [Content Sources > Feeds])

But getDocContent() method is not called.

1. How should set things getDocContent() method calls?
2. How Can I add item in adaptor-config.properties?

**[adaptor-config.properties]**

```
gsa.acceptsDocControlsHeader=true
adaptor.fullListingSchedule=0 3 * * *
adaptor.incrementalPollPeriodSecs=900
adaptor.docContentTimeoutSecs=180
adaptor.docHeaderTimeout=30
adaptor.pushDocIdsOnStartup=true
feed.maxUrls=5000
feed.name=Adaptor_Test
#gsa.version=7.2.0.G.286
gsa.characterEncoding=UTF-8
gsa.hostname=gsa.test.co.kr
gsa.admin.hostname=gsa.test.co.kr
journal.reducedMem=true
gsa.scoringType=content
server.dashboardPort=5679
server.docIdPath=/doc/
server.fullAccessHosts=
server.hostname=test.co.kr
server.maxWorkerThreads=16
server.port=5678
server.queueCapacity=160
server.reverseProxyPort=5678
server.secure=false
server.useCompression=true
```

**[run]**

```
java -cp adaptor-4.0.3-withlib.jar;examples/adaptor-4.0.3-examples.jar
com.google.enterprise.adaptor.examples.AdaptorTemplate
```

**[run log]**

```
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application logProductVersion
정보: Product Version: AdaptorTemplate  (unknown version)
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application logProductVersion
정보: Product Version: Google Adaptor Library  v4.1.0,  Google Inc.
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application main
정보: Version 1.7.0_55 of Java is supported.
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Config load
정보: New configuration file loaded
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application createHttpServer
정보: GSA host name: gsa.test.co.kr
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application createHttpServer
정보: server is listening on port #5678
9월 11, 2015 1:47:28 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application createDashboardHttpServer
정보: dashboard is listening on port #5679
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application realDaemonStart
정보: about to init com.google.enterprise.adaptor.examples.AdaptorTemplate
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocumentHandler initFullAccess
정보: When in secure mode, common names that are given full access to content: [gsa.test.co.kr]
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocumentHandler initFullAccess
정보: When not in secure mode, IPs that are given full access to content: [gsa.test.co.kr/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.GsaCommunicationHandler start
정보: Pushing once at program start
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushFullDocIdsFromAdaptor
정보: Beginning getDocIds
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushItems
정보: Pushing items
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushItems
정보: Pushing group of 2 items
9월 11, 2015 1:47:29 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.Application main
정보: doc content serving started
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushSizedBatchOfItems
정보: Pushing batch of 2 items to GSA
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushSizedBatchOfItems
정보: Sending items to GSA host: gsa.test.co.kr
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.GsaFeedFileSender handleGsaReply
정보: success message received. code:200
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushSizedBatchOfItems
정보: Pushing batch succeeded
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushSizedBatchOfItems
정보: Finished pushing batch of items
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushItems
정보: Pushed items
9월 11, 2015 1:47:30 오후 com.google.enterprise.adaptor.DocIdSender pushFullDocIdsFromAdaptor
정보: Completed getDocIds
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the feeds page on the GSA and make sure it processed the feed that you sent with 2 doc IDs ok.
It may be a problem with the URLS you have sent in that feed or you may have forgotten to add the URL pattern for your adaptor to the follow and crawl patterns on your GSA.